# Replacing string in regex with variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking to replace string with variable in regex.

```
re = new RegExp(/(?:^|\b)(asd)(?=\b|$)/, 'g')
```

After i get `re` i replace it and it works but this is limited to `asd` string.

How can i put variable `d` in place of `asd` string?
I tried following:

```
re = new RegExp('(?:^|\b)(' + d + ')(?=\b|$)', 'g')
```

But it didn't work, any help is appreciated. (I'm Using CoffeeScript)

Comment: Sure, you did not define *word boundary* with `"\b"`, but a backspace char. You need to use `"\\b"`. Just use `re = new RegExp('\\b' + d + '\\b', 'g')`. If you have special chars in `d`, you will come across a different issue though.

Comment: Thank you, i escaped "\b" and it works now: 
re = new RegExp('(?:^|\\b)('+d+')(?=\\b|$)', 'g')

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i may have special chars in variable, is there a way to escape them? Thanks Wiktor

Comment: Yes, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript